# Null in Aggregate Functions

Tags: sql

https://modern-sql.com/concept/null#aggregates says:

> Think About It How does the propagation of null through expressions
>   and the removal of null values prior to aggregation affect the
>   following expressions:
>
> SUM(a+b)
>
> SUM(a) + SUM(b)

I'm not really sure I understand what they mean and what is the difference.

I get that aggregation on NULL might give 0. But why there is a difference between these two statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this data:

```
a     b
1     NULL
NULL  2
3     3
```

The expression `sum(a + b)` is going to return 6.  Why?  The subsums are:

```
1 + NULL  --> NULL
NULL + 2  --> NULL
3 + 3     --> 6
```

The `sum()` of these values is 6.

If you do the calculation `sum(a) + sum(b)`, then the `NULL` values are combined in each column and you will get `(1 + 3) + (2 + 3)` --> 9.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=21c45c59a873bbeef9a14c0059984a6f) is a db<>fiddle, illustrating this effect.